# Check if two different elements contain specific words and if so fire event with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a unique problem. I have some code that I can't access duo to third party control, and I have customers on my e-commerce site that need to be aware of additional savings on particular combination of products. I am trying to create a Jquery solution. Here is the html:

```
<div class="pricing">
    <h2>Price &amp; Summary</h2>
    <dl>
            <dt>model-1</dt><!-- First string to check -->
            <dd>
                $2,499.99
            </dd>
                <dt>Product-Addon-Model-2</dt><!-- Second string to check -->
            <dd>
                    $1,699.99

            </dd>
            <dt class="discount">Promo Savings</dt><!--Append additional savings-->

            <dd class="discount">
                -$300.00
            </dd>

    </dl>
    <h3>
        Total
        <span class="total">

                $3,899.98

        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery I am trying to get right:

```
if ($("dl dt:contains('model-1', 'model-2', 'model-3', 'model-4', 'model-5')") && ("dl dt:contains('Product-Addon-Model-2', 'Product-Addon-Model-3')")){
        $( "<p>Additional discounts will be displayed in your cart</p>" ).appendTo( "dt.discount" ); 
}
```

One thing to note is I have many models for sale and I need to target very specific ones, and if one of the models exist on the page I need to check if they have selected two specific Addons. If both check points return true then the appendTO statement fires. Ideally I would like to store the two different lists of products into an Array, but :contains doesn't accept Array's. I am new to jquery and could use some pointers.

My problem being :contains doesn't seem to be working the way I had expect. If the "model-1" doesn't exist, but the "Product-Addon-Model-2" does then it fires. I need to make sure both specific wordlists are represented on the page in order for the append to fire. Not all of the words, but one word from each wordlist must be on the page.

It was suggested to add .length like so:

```
if ($("dl dt:contains('p6', 'm6', 'm7', 'i8', 'i10')").length && ("dl dt:contains('FlexFit 2', 'FlexFit 3')").length){
        $( "<p>Additional discounts will be displayed in your cart</p>" ).appendTo( "dt.discount" ); 
}
```

This comes up **undefined**

Comment: Seems like you're on the right way. Could you explain a bit more narrowly what problem exactly are you experiencing?

Comment: please note that `:contains` is case-sensitive: you have `Model-1` in your HTML, not `model-1`. Also, I'd advice you to omit data parsing in CSS selectors like `:contains` and do it with JavaScript as it is more reliable and flexible.

Comment: no problems. Just note that `:contains` is case-sensitive.

Comment: I made the change in my example. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: good. Is it working now or still some problems?

Comment: @AndrewDunai it is still having problems.

Comment: Thank you Oscar Jara this works great, and I even understand it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tested and working!

*There's no much to explain, just read code comments, If any doubt just let me know.*

```js
var EXPECTED_MODELS = [ // List of expected models to be found
        'model-1', 
        'model-2', 
        'model-3', 
        'model-4', 
        'model-5'
    ], 
    EXPECTED_PRODS = [ // List of expected products to be found
        'Product-Addon-Model-2', 
        'Product-Addon-Model-3'    
    ];

$(function() {
    
    var dts = $('dl dt'), // Get all 'dt' tags
        elem = $('dt.discount'), // Element used to display a message in UI
        msg = '<p>Additional discounts will be displayed in your cart</p>'; // Message to be displayed

    // Check if model and product exist then show discount message
    if (isExpectedModelAndProduct(dts)) {
        showMsg(msg, elem);
    }

});

/**
 * Used to check if text inside '<dt>' tags from third party HTML matches 
 * any of the entries in EXPECTED_MODELS and EXPECTED_PRODS arrays.
 *
 * @param {Array} arr Contains all '<dt>' tags
 * @returns {Boolean} match
 */
function isExpectedModelAndProduct(arr) {
    var match = false,
        modelExist = false, 
        prodExist = false, 
        dt;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        dt = arr[i];
        if (dt) {
            if (exist(dt.innerText, EXPECTED_MODELS)) {
                modelExist = true;
            }
            if (exist(dt.innerText, EXPECTED_PRODS)) {
                prodExist = true;
            }
            if (modelExist && prodExist) {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return match;
};

/**
 * Used to check if 'text' exist in specific array.
 * 
 * @param {String} text To be found
 * @param {Array} arr To be searched
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
function exist(text, arr) {
    return ($.inArray(text, arr) != -1);
};
                
/**
 * Show a message in UI using specific element
 *
 * @param {String} msg To be displayed
 * @param {Object} elem To be used for displaying the message
 */
function showMsg(msg, elem) {
    $(msg).appendTo(elem);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing">
     <h2>Price &amp; Summary</h2>

    <dl><dt>model-1</dt>

        <!-- First string to check -->
        <dd>$2,499.99</dd> <dt>Product-Addon-Model-2</dt>

        <!-- Second string to check -->
        <dd>$1,699.99</dd> <dt class="discount">Promo Savings</dt>

        <!--Append additional savings-->
        <dd class="discount">-$300.00</dd>
    </dl>
     <h3>
        Total
        <span class="total">
                $3,899.98
        </span>
    </h3>

</div>
```